# How to store information for each element of a config file that is prone to change (PYTHON)

Tags: python, class, data-structures, config, openpyxl

I have a config file (.txt file which I use Python's ConfigParser to read), which I later read into Python as a list of employee initials and names that looks like this:

```
[CSE]
MB = Mike
SI = Samantha
TH = Tom
...And so on. The length of the config file is prone to change as more or less people are added.
```

My program has to read an excel spreadsheet. I use Openpyxl. In the spreadsheet there are hundreds of rows of info (each representing an incident). There are four categories with multiple items in each. (Data, wifi, voice, cable). For each employee, I have to report the category, and then each month the incident was completed by. I’m confused on how to store the information for each employee given the config file list could change (either by length or by employee)?
My supervisor suggested making a new object in a class for each employee but how would I store info and reference each one?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand correctly your main issue but from my last Python assessment where I have to generate html report from syslog.log where each line contains several information for each user. The best approach is to first append usernames only into usernames.csv file and to save all different information in columns.csv file, this could be done using regex and operator modules. Once you have the correct script to generate the 2 mentioned csv files, all the rest will be kid game. If you want me to send you my script assessment, you tell me, if it does not help it will give you hints.

Comment: Thank you for the response! That's definitely something to think about. My main issue is that I have a list of employee names. My program has to read a cvs file, and store information for each employee in the list. I am confused on how to store information for each employee without hardcoding the employee names into the program? (As the list of employees can change)

Comment: ok no problem bro. I am gonna send you my script with explanation. just give me few mimutes. for the fact that usernames.csv needs to be updated, i think the best approach would be a single csv file which contains usernames only and a scritp that checks usernames in the original files usong regex, if it is not in usernsmes.csv, append it.

Comment: don't forget to click on triangle up and vote as answer. happy coding.

Comment: if you need a python script to convert csv to html you tell me

Comment: Thank you, however that is more advanced than the question I was asking for my script. I am not working in html.

Comment: I am just confused on how to store information for each string in a list. then report the information by each string

Answer (score 0):

This is the syslog.log content:

```
Jan 31 00:09:39 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#4217] (mdouglas)
Jan 31 00:16:25 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#1754] (noel)
Jan 31 00:21:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (breee)
Jan 31 00:44:34 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (ac)
Jan 31 01:00:50 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#4709] (blossom)
Jan 31 01:29:16 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#6518] (rr.robinson)
Jan 31 01:33:12 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (mcintosh)
Jan 31 01:43:10 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (jackowens)
Jan 31 01:49:29 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (mdouglas)
Jan 31 02:30:04 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (oren)
Jan 31 02:55:31 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (xlg)
Jan 31 03:05:35 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 03:08:55 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (blossom)
Jan 31 03:39:27 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (bpacheco)
Jan 31 03:47:24 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (enim.non)
Jan 31 04:30:04 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (rr.robinson)
Jan 31 04:31:49 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (oren)
Jan 31 04:32:49 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (mcintosh)
Jan 31 04:44:23 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 04:44:46 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (jackowens)
Jan 31 04:49:28 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Permission denied while closing ticket (flavia)
Jan 31 05:12:39 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (oren)
Jan 31 05:18:45 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (sri)
Jan 31 05:23:14 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#1097] (breee)
Jan 31 05:35:00 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (nonummy)
Jan 31 05:45:30 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7115] (noel)
Jan 31 05:51:30 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR The ticket was modified while updating (flavia)
Jan 31 05:57:46 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#2253] (nonummy)
Jan 31 06:12:02 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (oren)
Jan 31 06:26:38 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (xlg)
Jan 31 06:32:26 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#7298] (ahmed.miller)
Jan 31 06:36:25 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (flavia)
Jan 31 06:57:00 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Connection to DB failed (jackowens)
Jan 31 06:59:57 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#7255] (oren)
Jan 31 07:59:56 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Ticket doesn't exist (flavia)
Jan 31 08:01:40 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Tried to add information to closed ticket (jackowens)
Jan 31 08:03:19 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Closed ticket [#1712] (britanni)
Jan 31 08:22:37 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Created ticket [#2860] (mcintosh)
Jan 31 08:28:07 ubuntu.local ticky: ERROR Timeout while retrieving information (montanap)
```

This is my assessment code which will creates 2 files: error_message.csv where every different error log entry will be counted. user_statistics.csv where 3 columns will be created as follow: user, info, error and each column will be filled according to each user log activities.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import csv
import operator
import sys

per_user = {}
errors = {}

logfile = 'syslog.log'
f = open(logfile, 'r')

errorfile = 'error_message.csv'
userfile = 'user_statistics.csv'

for log in f:
        result = re.search(r"ticky: ([\w+]*):? ([\w' ]*) [\[[0-9#]*\]?]? ?\((.*)\)$", log)
        if result.group(2) not in errors.keys():
                errors[result.group(2)] = 0
        errors[result.group(2)] += 1
        if result.group(3) not in per_user.keys():
                per_user[result.group(3)] = {}
                per_user[result.group(3)]["INFO"] = 0
                per_user[result.group(3)]["ERROR"] = 0

        if result.group(1) == "INFO":
                per_user[result.group(3)]["INFO"] += 1
        elif result.group(1) == "ERROR":
                per_user[result.group(3)]["ERROR"] += 1

errors = sorted(errors.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
per_user = sorted(per_user.items())

f.close()
errors.insert(0, ('Error', 'Count'))

f = open(errorfile, 'w')
for error in errors:
        a,b = error
        f.write(str(a)+','+str(b)+'\n')
f.close()

f = open(userfile, 'w')
f.write("Username,INFO,ERROR\n")
for stats in per_user:
        a, b = stats
        f.write(str(a)+','+str(b["INFO"])+','+str(b["ERROR"])+'\n')
```

You can now visualize the **__error_message.csv __and user_statistics.csv** by converting them to HTML pages. To do this, pass the files one by one to the script csv_to _html.py file, like we did in the previous section.

First give write permission to the directory that would host that HTML page:

```
sudo chmod  o+w /var/www/html
```

Then to convert the error_message.csv into HTML file run the following command:

```
./csv_to_html.py error_message.csv /var/www/html/<html-filename>.html
```

Replace  with the name of your choice.

To convert user_statistics.csv into HTML file, run the following command:

```
./csv_to_html.py user_statistics.csv /var/www/html/<html-filename>.html
```

Replace  with the new name

Now, to view these HTML pages, open any web-browser and open the html page with your browser.

After I passed this assessment, I learned that in many complex cases, creating new files and appending your matched regex is the best approach to have a comfortable job.

Hopefully it will help you in this task or in others.